# Python3 Error: TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

Tags: json, python-3.x, python-requests

I'd like to get the latest posts id from a subreddit. Reddit is have basic api for this. You can get json so i want gives data and decode it but i have a error.

```
root@archi-sunucu:~/yusuf/www# python3 reddit.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "reddit.py", line 24, in <module>
    json = json.loads(resp.text())
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
root@archi-sunucu:~/yusuf/www# python3 reddit.py
```

my code:

```py
url = "https://www.reddit.com/r/" + subreddit + "/" + feed + ".json?sort=" + feed + "&limit=6"

resp = requests.get(url, verify=False)
json = json.loads(resp.text())

print(json["data"]["children"][0]["data"]["id"])
```

thanks for helps...

Comment: If it is not callable, don't call it: `json.loads(resp.text)`

Comment: Did you read what I wrote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You complained that this expression `raise`s an error:

> json.loads(resp.text())

Well, let's break that down into something simpler,
so the line number tells us exactly what part of your code is failing.

```
temp = resp.text()
json.loads(temp)
```

Now we see that the 2nd line doesn't even execute,
it fails in the 1st line attempting to compute something
to assign to the temporary variable.

Examine `resp` and its attribute with tools
like `help(resp)`, `dir(resp)`, `type(resp.text)`, `repr(resp.text)`.
You will soon learn the `.text` attribute is a `str`.
That is not a callable function, so python `raises` an error.
Use the value directly, without a call:

```
json = json.loads(resp.text)
```